# Single quotes in plugin wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I create a wp wordpress, and i have a problem with the output of single quotes.
I would that the user, in admin panel, insert a string for error message. The user will insert a string, but if it will insert a string with a single quotes, I would in output a string with single quotes.

The code:

```
    <?php if(($wpmailup['emailRequired'] == 'yes') && ($wpmailup['emailShow'] == 'yes')): ?>
        if(!(sub_email.match(/^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.'"])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.'"])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/)))
        {
            jQ('#show-response').html("<?php _e($wpmailup['invalidAddress']); ?>");
            viewInfoIcon('info');
            return false;
        }
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if(($wpmailup['mobileRequired'] == 'yes') && ($wpmailup['mobileShow'] == 'yes')): ?>
        if(jQ.trim(sub_phone) == "")
        {
            jQ('#show-response').html('<?php _e($wpmailup['invalidPhone']); ?>');
            viewInfoIcon('info');
            return false;
        }
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Any ideas?

thanks a lots guys

Answer (score 0):

You can use addslashes php function to resolve single Quotes problem.

```
i.e, jQ('#show-response').html('<?php _e(addslashes($wpmailup['invalidPhone'])); ?>');
```